# Determine the normwise condition of the operation $f_1(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, normed-spaces, rounding-error

> Determine the normwise condition of the operation
>   $f_1(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$

I unfortunately have no idea how a task like that can be solved.

There doesn't seem to be much source on the internet about it. But I found this in a book:

> Let $X=\mathbb{R}^{n}, Y=\mathbb{R}^m \text{with fixed norms, } x \in X, f: X \rightarrow Y, x \neq 0, f(x) \neq 0$
>
> $c_{abs}$ stands for absolute condition and $c_{rel}$ for relative
>   condition.
>
> $$c_{abs}=c_{abs}(x) = \text{lim sup}_{\tilde{x} \rightarrow
> x}\frac{\left \| f(\tilde{x})-f(x) \right \|_Y}{\left \| \tilde{x}-x
> \right \|_X}= \text{lim sup}_{\tilde{x} \rightarrow x}
> \frac{\text{absolute error of }f(\tilde{x})}{\text{absolute error of }
> \tilde{x}}$$
>
> $$c_{rel} = c_{rel}(x) = \text{lim sup}_{\tilde{x} \rightarrow
> x}\frac{\frac{\left \| f(\tilde{x})-f(x) \right \|_Y}{\left \| f(x)
> \right \|_Y}}{\frac{\left \| \tilde{x}-x \right \|_X}{\left \| x
> \right \|_X}}= \text{lim sup}_{\tilde{x} \rightarrow
> x}\frac{\text{relative error of }f(\tilde{x})}{\text{relative error of
> }\tilde{x}}$$
>
> These conditions are also called *normwise conditions*.

I'm not even sure if this is the correct thing that is needed to solve this task. But I hope you can show me at this example how a task like that can be solved?

I wouldn't know what to do in an exam else, because there is nothing so far I can read about it :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your definition we have

$$c_{abs}(x,y)=
\limsup_{(\overline{x},\overline{y})\to(x,y)}
\frac{\left|\frac{\overline{x}}{\overline{y}}-\frac{x}y\right|}
{\sqrt{{\left(\overline{x}-x\right)}^2+{\left(\overline{y}-y\right)}^2}}$$

Another way to write this is as follows:

$$c_{abs}(x,y)=
\limsup_{(h_x,h_y)\to(0,0)}
\frac{\left|\frac{x+h_x}{y+h_y}-\frac{x}y\right|}
{\sqrt{{h_x}^2+{h_y}^2}}$$

Does this expression look more familiar to you? Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand the first notation. Only in the enumerator, it should be saying  $\left \|  \right \|$ instead of $| |$ right? But I don't seem to understand the second notation. Why is it good to write it like that?

Comment: The norm of the numerator is the norm of the real numbers, usually the absolute value. The second notation writes $(\overline{x},\overline{y})=(x+h_x,y+h_y)$. As $(\overline{x},\overline{y})\to(x,y)$, $(h_x,h_y)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: Now after trying myself on paper, I don't understand why the denominator in first notation is like that. I have on paper:
$$\text{lim sup}_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}) \rightarrow (x,y)} \frac{\left \| f(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})-f(x,y) \right \|}{\left \| (\tilde{x},\tilde{y})-(x,y) \right \|} = \text{lim sup}_{(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}) \rightarrow (x,y)} \frac{\left | \frac{\tilde{x}}{y} - \frac{x}{y} \right |}{\sqrt{(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})^2 - (x,y)^2}}$$

How do you get to $\sqrt{(\tilde{x}-x)^2 +(\tilde{y}-y)^2}$ ?

Comment: That is the usual, Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Your expression is incorrect.

Comment: Ah now I understand that too! What would be the final solution then? I don't think we can calculate the limit because we don't know if the nominator is greater or lower than the denominator, we don't have any values given. I have asked this here too and @DonAntonio explained: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317149/whats-limsup-h-x-h-y-to0-0-frac-left-fracxh-xyh-y-fracxy-ri?noredirect=1#comment4768743_2317149

Comment: I don't understand that observation. $x$ and $y$ are fixed.

Comment: How would you write the solution then? Can I just choose some $x$ and $y$, then calculate $\text{lim sup}$ ?

Comment: The idea si to do precisely this, for each pair $(x,y)$. That's what I understood from your question; I have never actually hear of normwise conditions.

Comment: It appears to me that the $\limsup$ is $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y^2}$.

Comment: We got a different formula for solving, it's much easier but our teacher of course reveals the good things when it's late.. anyway thank you very much, you helped me a lot!! :)) Without your answer I couldn't have used the new formula, too.

Comment: Glad to have helped!